# LINUX: is it posible to show on tty1 the same thing I see when logged in via ssh?

Tags: terminal, gnu-screen

I am logged in via ssh int a foreign Linux box, and the owner want to assist me from tty1. I tried to convince him to log also in and share a screen with me.

He insists he want to assist me from tty1.
Is there a way to make a screen with a console and a terminal ?

I want to explain a bit more .
A tty is a native terminal device, the back-end is either hardware or kernel emulated.

A pty (pseudo terminal device) is a terminal device which is emulated by an other program (example: xterm, screen, or ssh are such programs).

My question is if I can make somehow to share a session with a tty in the way we share sessions on screen.

Comment: You already tagged your question with `screen`, which is capable of doing this (`screen -x`). What exactly is your problem with it?

Comment: how can I add a tty to a screen ? When I open a screen I can only multiply my session.

Answer (score 0):

You can share a screen session from multiple terminals with the `-x` parameter. It doesn't matter what kind of terminal it is.

1. Log in via SSH
2. Start screen

   ```
   screen
   ```
3. Log in on another terminal with the same user
4. Start screen and attach it to the existing session

   ```
   screen -x
   ```

Now both terminals have the same session, both can see and type.

Comment: and how can I do it if I cannot log in from tty1 because I am not there? can I attach the session without being at tty?